# How to change color of NSPathControl

Tags: cocoa, nspathcontrol

Please take a look at this picture:[image]

I know how to change the text color:

```
  NSPathComponentCell *cell = [_pathControl pathComponentCells].firstObject;
  cell setTextColor:[NSColor redColor];
```

But i'd also like to change the color of the arrows, anyone know how to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not supported out of the box - you need to roll your own.

Or have a look at the various 3rd party implementations out there like ITPathbar:
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/itpathbar

Comment: i have already reviewed the ITPathbar, but could you tell me what should i do in order to change the color of the arrow?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to modify [NSPathControlItem/attributedTitle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspathcontrolitem/1388287-attributedtitle):

(Limitation: macOS 10.10+)

```
    for pathControlItem in pathControl.pathItems {
        let range =  NSMakeRange(0, pathControlItem.attributedTitle.length)
        let attributedTitle = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: pathControlItem.attributedTitle)
        attributedTitle.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: yourColor, range: range)
        pathControlItem.attributedTitle = attributedTitle
    }
```

Or try to create subclass.(I didn't test it)